# Diffeomorphism between a triangle and a square?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Is there always a diffeomorphism between $(0,1)^2$ and any given (not degenerate) triangle?

Comment: *Diffeo*-morphism?? I would doubt. At maximum between the open *inner* part of the square and the triangle.

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: @Berci is referring to the fact that [every convex open subsets of the Euclidean plane is diffeomorphic to the unit open ball](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/4516#4516).

Comment: @Berci Sorry, the second sentence didn't parse. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. So if I take $(0,1)^2$ then I'm good? (Set of measure zero is nothing to me)

Comment: Question changed, somebody go for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "triangle" you mean the *open set* bounded by three line segments (the boundaries themselves are not included), then [yes, every convex open subset of the Euclidean plane is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/4516#4516).

Comment: In fact every simply connected open subset of the Euclidean plane is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Jacob: I see two ways to conclude that, one of which involves the Riemannian mapping theorem. Do you have in mind a easier proof?

Comment: I had the Riemannian mapping theorem in mind.